# NodeJS Async/Await Exporting a Variable

Tags: node.js, module, promise, export

Me again busting b***s ... 
I'm sorry to have to come back to you guys, but I find the information available online very confusing and can't seem to find an appropriate answer to my problem. 
So if one of you wizards/gods of the Node could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I'm trying to export a variable that yields from a promise to a different module. 
Here's my code:

The main:

```
//app.js <--- This is where I need the variable exported.

var sp1 = require('./module');

var somePromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Hey! It worked the second time!');
});


async function exec() {
  const message1 = await sp1.msg
  const message2 = await somePromise2
  console.log('Success', message1, message2);
}

exec()
```

and the module with the promise:

```
//module.js

var somePromise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var msg = '';
  resolve(msg = 'Hey! It worked!');
});

module.exports = {
  somePromise1,
}
```

As you can see the somePromise1, is actually the same as somePromise2 but in a different module. Thing is, I apparently can't seem to get the msg variable to be exported, it yields an undefined (if I do everything locally: in the same file, it works seemlessly).

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry in advance if you find this is a duplicate of an existing question... 
I'crawled SO since yesterday for an answer and moved the code around but nothing seems to apply...

Comment: You are not exporting the `msg` variable. You're only exporting the `somePromise1` promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in importing and a mistake in using the promise:

```
//app.js <--- This is where I need the variable exported.

var sp1 = require('./module').somePromise1;

var somePromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Hey! It worked the second time!');
});


async function exec() {
  const message1 = await sp1; 
  const message2 = await somePromise2;
  console.log('Success', message1, message2);
}

exec()
```

Comment: It worked! Could help me a little more with the whys? I mean, why do I need to add '.somePromise1' and not just specify './module' ?

Comment: Sorry, Thanks a million! (btw)

Comment: @Ardzii I recommend that you read a good article on import / export: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/